# how to identify filename and code line from error message?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, appinsights

Newbie question: I'm getting the following error message in AppInsights from an Ionic webapp in production

```
    Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')
    at new u (https://ps.myapp.app/2806.694179fdbc052681.js:1:4851)
    at dt.component.u.ɵfac [as factory] (https://ps.suplai.app/2806.694179fdbc052681.js:1:27122)
    at Ue (https://ps.myapp.app/main.750663c576a071b3.js:1:449610)
    at Nl (https://ps.myapp.app/main.750663c576a071b3.js:1:500147)
    at Mg (https://ps.myapp.app/main.750663c576a071b3.js:1:500218)
    at xu.create (https://ps.myapp.app/main.750663c576a071b3.js:1:500504)
    at tD.createComponent (https://ps.myapp.app/main.750663c576a071b3.js:1:506694)
    at _.activateWith (https://ps.myapp.app/main.750663c576a071b3.js:1:48467)
    at Go.activateRoutes (https://ps.myapp.app/main.750663c576a071b3.js:1:586856)
    at https://ps.myapp.app/main.750663c576a071b3.js:1:585768
```

how can I identify the filename and code line associated with the message?

Answer (score 0):

AppInsights supports uploading source maps for javascript as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/source-map-support

Below the callstack window you will find the Unminify option to tick and start configuring the blob storage needed to store the source maps.